# C++ Clang_format_style forcing 'newline' after method return value data type in VSCode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, formatting, clang

I have a **formatting problem in VSCode**.

I'm writing a program with many methods in one Class, something like this:

```cpp
class CPersonalAgenda {
public:
    CPersonalAgenda(void);
    ~CPersonalAgenda(void);
    bool add(const string &name,
             const string &surname,
             const string &email,
             unsigned int salary);
    bool changeName(const string &email,
                    const string &newName,
                    const string &newSurname);
    // here is the problem
    bool
    setSalary(const string &name, const string &surname, unsigned int salary);
    // ---
    unsigned int getSalary(const string &name, const string &surname) const;
    // AND SO ON ...
}
```

As you can see, one of the methods is being formatted in a way, where there is a newline character added after it.

My formatting settings in `C_Cpp: Clang_format_style` in VSC settings are: `{ BasedOnStyle: LLVM, AlignTrailingComments: true, FixNamespaceComments: false, AccessModifierOffset: -4, IndentWidth: 4, BinPackArguments: false, BinPackParameters: false, AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: false, ExperimentalAutoDetectBinPacking: false}`

Any ideas why this happends? I can't seem to figure out why it would ***single out only one method.***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look for `ColumnLimit` in `clang-format --dump-config`. There are must be something like  `ColumnLimit: 80`.

Either increase the limit

```
ColumnLimit: 110
```

Or disable the column limit

```
ColumnLimit: 0
```

Or re-word the function declaration

```
    bool setSalary(const std::string &name,
                   const std::string &surname,
                   unsigned int salary);
```

Or set

```
BinPackParameters: true
```